# How to use client-side cursor for SqlConnection/SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 instance and a client application written in C#.

From this application I retrieve data using the code below. Using some empirical testing, it seems *server-side cursors* are being used. For my particular use-case I would like to use *client-side cursors*. How can this be done?

How can I make my connection use client-side cursors?

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear/>
   <add name="myDB" 
        connectionString="Server=SERVER\INSTANCE;Database=test"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

C# client code:

```
using (var connection = OpenConnection())
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "dbo.my_stored_procedure";

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object retrievedObject = reader.GetValue(0);
                // Use object...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Useful links:

- [Client-Side Cursors Versus Server-Side Cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266531(v=vs.60).aspx)
- [Cursor Types (SQLSRV Driver)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I don't even know what a client-side cursor is. Can you provide a link to an article on that feature?

Comment: Did you notice that you have linked to an article about Visual Studio 6.0?

Comment: And that SQLSRV is a driver for PHP?

Comment: What makes you think that _any_ cursor is being used?

Comment: @JohnSaunders At some point, the client or the server needs to know where the next row is - hence a cursor. Since the introduction of ADO.NET the terminology might have changed. Though, I would assume that the underlying kernel code does something similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by a "client-side cursor" you mean you want to transfer all the results to the client immediately rather than progressively reading from server as it executes, just load it into a DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
foreach (var row in dt.Rows) { /* Your data is in row now */}
```

Comment: Two good answers :) I believe `dt.Read(reader)` should be `dt.Load(reader)`.

Answer (score 6):

In the old ADO there was `CursorLocationEnum` which allows one to select if a client side or a server side cursor should be used. ADO.NET works in a different way. ADO.NET Datareader is an equivalent of a server side cursor and it cannot work as a client side cursor.

My understanding of a client side cursor is that it is used when all data are firstly downloaded to a client and then processed. It means that after the initial fetch of data no additional requests are sent to a server. If I'm right, it means that ADO.NET DataSet is an equivalent of a client side cursor in ADO.NET. It is an offline/disconnected data structure that can be populated with DataAdapter. This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163940.aspx) can be also useful.